# How to build special turing machine

Tags: algorithm, turing-machines

Good day. I have a question. Many people are familiar with the Turing machine. The following task arose, which I can’t solve for a long time: there is an alphabet consisting of the letters "X", "Y" "Z", if the number of letters "Z" in the word is exactly 2 more than the letters "X", replace the second letter "Z" with "X". Otherwise, leave the word unchanged. Considering that I cannot change the original word and the tape is infinite (that is, I cannot write an infinite number of states for the machine), I do not understand how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it more clear, if the input is for example:

```
XXXYZZZZZ
```

then the output you need is:

```
XXXYZXZZZZ
```

And if the input is:

```
XXYZZ
```

Then everything needs to stay the same, since (number of Z's) - (number of X's) != 2

```
XXYZZ
```

If I understood the problem correctly, in the way I defined above, then here comes the solution with Morphett's TM Simulator, with $ sign as left-end marker:

```
1 $ $ r 1
1 X A r 2
1 Y Y r 4

2 X X r 2
2 B B r 2
2 Y Y r 2
2 Z B R 3

3 Y Y l 3
3 B B l 3
3 X X l 3
3 A A r 1
3 Z Z l 3

4 Y Y r 4
4 B B r 4
4 Z B r 5
4 _ _ l 7

5 Z B r 6
5 _ _ l 7

6 Z Z l 7
6 _ _ l 8

7 B Z l 7
7 Y Y l 7
7 A X l 7
7 $ $ r 12 

8 B Z l 8
8 Y Y l 8
8 A X l 8
8 $ $ r 9

9 X X r 9
9 Y Y r 9
9 Z Z r 10

10 Z X r 11

11 Z Z r 11
11 _ _ l halt

12 X X r 12
12 Y Y r 12
12 Z Z r 12
12 _ _ l halt
```

Copy this code and then paste it to http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html

From advanced options, set initial state to 1 from 0.

Do not forget to add a "$" to beginning of every input.

Comment: According to the condition of the problem, I cannot use letters that are not in the alphabet (in your example, this is "A" and "B")

Comment: And it doesn't work if i start from "Z"

Comment: Well, since you specified what the problem is and not what you exactly need in detail, I could not have known. 
None of the problems you mentioned change the main algorithm, the logic of the machine. You can easily transform the machine I designed for your purposes.